# Множественное редактирование в MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

прошу помочь с решением моего вопроса.
Разрабатываю Node.JS приложение.
У меня есть 2 массива. Первый массив содержит _id записей, которые я хочу изменить.  Второй массив содержит новые данные которые я хочу обновить в Записях. Я хочу взять нулевой элемент первого массива (содержащий _id записи) и изменить в этой записи одно поле информацией из нулевого элемента второго массива и так далее. Как лучше это реализовать, не понимаю можно ли передать массив в качестве аргумента? Получится ли тут использовать updateMany?

Comment: `updateMany` обновляет кучу документов одинаковым способом. А вам нужно каждый - своим. Поэтому не подходит. Подойдет пройти циклом и сделать `updateOne`. Но лучше посмотрите как работает Bulk: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/#example - он будет работать быстрее.